# Составное именное сказуемое

Tags: сказуемое

Может ли именная часть составного именного сказуемого быть выражена инфинитивом?
На [Этом](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304304) сайте утверждают, что да. 
На других сайтах инфинитив не упоминается. Если именная часть - инфинитив, то это уже составное глагольное, а не именное сказуемое. 
Т.е. есть мнение, что именная часть в СИС не может быть выражена инфинитивом, да и вообще глаголом. 
И в предложении "Его утеха – по лесам скитаться" "есть скитаться" - это составное глагольное, а не именное, как утверждает сайт, сказуемое.

Что думаете?

Answer (score 2):

"Его утеха – по лесам скитаться" Утеха какова? - скитаться (=скитания). Предмет и признак предмета (а не действие предмета).

Неопределённая форма глагола - инфинитив - потому и неопределённая, что семантически аналогична именительному падежу имени существительного со значением действия. Существительное скитания обозначает действие как предмет, а инфинитив скитаться - действие как процесс.

Классификация видов глагола происходит с учётом лексического и грамматического значений.

Вне словосочетания инфинитив называет действие безотносительно к наклонению, времени, лицу, числу, следовательно, в приведённом предложении инфинитив не может быть простым глагольным сказуемым, потому что простое глагольное сказуемое выражается глаголами в форме любого наклонения, времени и лица, ведь здесь в одном слове выражены и лексическое, и грамматическое значения. Инфинитив может употребляться в простом глагольном сказуемом как несогласованная экспрессивная форма со значением энергичного начала действия - с грамматическим значением настоящего времени: "Наша братия - ругаться" (= ругается, как заругается).

```
"есть скитаться" - это составное глагольное, а не именное
```

Составным глагольным "есть скитаться" быть не может, потому что в схеме СГС=
приинфинитивная часть + инфинитив  вспомогательная (приинфинитивная) часть выражает грамматическое значение сказуемого, а также дополнительную характеристику действия — указание на его начало, середину или конец (фазисное значение) или возможность, желательность, степень обычности и другие характеристики, описывающие отношение субъекта действия к этому действию (модальное значение). Тогда как в нашем предложении ни фазисного, ни модального значения у вспомогательного глагола нет.

Здесь есть нулевая связка ЕСТЬ с отвлечённым значением. Наличие отвлечённой связки, которая  выражает грамматическое значение настоящего времени, говорит о присутствии имени, при этом отнесение сказуемых, выраженных наречием, причастием и междометием, а в данном случае инфинитивом, является условным, здесь нет налицо ИМЕНИ, но есть близость к функции имён в роли сказуемого (название признака).

Следовательно, это составное именное. Когда-то в пособии для старшеклассников  о предложениях типа "Жить - родине служить" так и говорили: при отсутствии глагола-связки в именном составном сказуемом  между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится тире и назывались случаи: сущ. в им.п. - сущ. в им.п.; инф. - инф; сущ. в им.п - инф. и т.д. Потому сущ. и инфинитив и взаимозаменяемы, что роль их похожа.
`

Comment: Спасибо! Я на Грамоте уже писала, что методом "от противного" можно доказать что это СИС.

Comment: Настя, я что-то не понял: Грамота утверждает, что это СГС?

Comment: Нет, как я поняла, они утверждают что это СИС.

Comment: Видел. Ну СИС - это еще можно как-то подтянуть под непротиворечивую систему.  Но никак не СГС, как они вначале несли.  
Вся беда в том, что они ориентируются на один-единственный источник, пусть авторитетный, но нигде более не подтвержденный, даже его, источника, автором. Розенталь дает другую, на "грамоте" тоже представленную.  
А поскольку любая модель грамматики естественного языка допускает как минимум альтернативный разбор предложения, в ход идут ссылки на авторитетов. И тут уже воля считающего, какую из двух (или более) трактовок принимать. Я дал третью, тоже, имхо, правильную.

Comment: Серж, это не грамота, это форум. Они успели поменять свою точку зрения. Сначала было СГС, потом нашли какой-то богом забытый учебник, где говорилось, что СИС.  
Там единственный специалист - Эмилия, остальные в большинстве - дилетанты вроде нас с вами, но в отличие от нас - дилетанты воинствующие (последнее время). А вообще присоединятесь к той дискуссии, там её удобнее вести в форме диалога. Я из бана выйду - поддержу.  
  
Настя, "метод от противного" работает тогда и только тогда, когда справедлив т.н. "закон исключенного третьего". Здесь это неверно. Есть масса третьих возможностей.

Comment: (+)
Я не буду, пожалуй, здесь всего писать, дождусь "Грамоты", но обозначу. Чтобы сработал "метод от противного" необходимо в начшем случае показать:   
а) что это вообще составное сказуемое, а не простое (вариант разбора - у меня).  
б) что это не два предложения с двумя главными частями.  
в) что это не еще что-нибудь, чего мы тут не видим (как у Розенталя).   
  
Это надо показать на строгих формулировках, а не на мнениях, пусть и авторитетных. Т.е. так же строго, как показана невозможность трактовки примера как СГС, иначе сама идея "от противного" будет выхолощенной.

Answer (score 2):

Мое мнение.
Именная часть составного именного сказуемого м.б. выражена по-разному:

1) специализированными словоформами имен: именами существительными, именами прилагательными и причастиями, порядковым именами числительными, некоторыми местоимениями:
 Он ДОВОЛЕН поездкой. Ты КТО? Я СМУЩЕН этим предложением.;

2) неспециализированными словоформами имен: косвенными падежами имен существительных и субстантивированных слов:
Все были В ТРЕВОГЕ.;

3)неизменяемыми словами: наречиями, деепричастиями, компаративами, словосочетаниями, междометиями и ИНФИНИТИВОМ:
Моя сестра ЗАМУЖЕМ. Этот человек --- ОЙ-ОЙ-ОЙ! Дерево В ДВА ОБХВАТА. Заниматься спортом --- СОХРАНЯТЬ здоровье.

Историческая справка. Инфинитив --- это застывшая форма Дательного падежа отглагольного имени основ на I краткое, которое совмещало в себе свойства имени и глагола, обозначало одновременно и ПРЕДМЕТНОЕ понятие, и действие. Возможно, это сказалось и на синтаксических свойствах инфинитива, в частности --- на возможности быть ИМЕННОЙ частью составного именного сказуемого.

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксис современного русского языка, курс лекций, 2013 год.

Именная часть может выражаться инфинитивом: Уйти значило признать свое поражение. Понимать - значит сочувствовать.

Примечание.

Инфинитив может входить в глагольное и именное сказуемое. В глагольном сказуемом он зависит от вспомогательного глагола (хочет/может/начал читать), а в именном - соединяется с подлежащим с помощью связки.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Ничего удивительного в этом нет, та как инфинитив имеет назывную функцию: читать - чтение. Он любит читать (СГС) - Его любимое занятие - чтение книг/читать книги (СИС).

Comment: Это не Настин пример.

Comment: Не вижу разницы: "Его утеха - скитание/скитаться по лесам". Нашла еще один новый учебник: Федосюк М.Ю. Синтаксис современного русского языка. В нем подобные предложения выделены в отдельную группу и называются инфинитивными сказуемыми: "Наша задача - учиться. Жизнь прожить - не поле перейти". Их специфика в том, что они выражают не предметы, а ситуации. Если подлежащим является сущ. со значением отвлеченного понятия, то инфинитив раскрывает это понятие путем отождествления, как  это делают сущ. в предложениях вида "Экзамен - это проверка знаний"(СИС).

Comment: София, про "не вижу разницы"
эти примеры с двумя инфинитивами в роли главных членов у Розенталя разбираются. Позже ссылку дам. С ними вообще каша. Лучше сюда не приплетать.  
  
Ну а про "чтение" это совершенно особый случай. Попробуйте-ка заменить в настином примере тире на "стало". "Его удел стало по лесам скитаться?"))) Только "его удел**ом**".  

Вот выделение таких сказуемых в отдельную группу мне тоже нравится. Тоже как вариант. Я надеюсь, эта вновь вводимая группа - не считается подгруппой СИС или СГС?

Comment: В этом учебнике инфинитивные сказуемые считаются отдельной группой.

Comment: Ну да, я уточнял, "отдельная" - это *и от СГС, и от СИС*. Как бы третья в списке возможных вариантов составных сказуемых.  
Это мне, повторюсь, вполне нравится. Поскольку ни тем, ни другим не являются - и в СИС их за уши притянули "от противного".  
Я вот не помню, когда я раньше сталкивался с Федосюком - и какое о нем мнение у специалистов. Не в изгоях ли он ходит?

Comment: http://istina.msu.ru/profile/fedosyuk/ На изгоя не похож, учебники, статьи печатает, но названия статей какие-то революционные. Впрочем, народ интересуется  http://ahhaqu.gdz.quantum-labs.co.id/?page=fedosyuk_uchebnik

Answer (score 0):

[[@Настя_Р](/users/4220/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F_%D1%80)](/users/4220/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F_%D1%80), я не знаю, может ли быть такое в принципе, но в вашем примере - точно нет. Тут просто нет составного сказуемого.

Во фразах типа "Работа певца - петь", "Веселое занятие - кататься с горки" ну и в вашем "Его утеха – по лесам скитаться" слова "петь", "кататься", "скитаться"  - второстепенные члены предложения (дополнения). А тире на месте глагола-связки - простое сказуемое.

Это ясно уже потому, что не выполняется один из главных признаков составного глагольного сказуемого. У такого сказуемого основная часть (субъектный инфинитив) должна относиться к подлежащему, а не к чему-то еще. В наших же примерах это не так. С горки катается не занятие, поет не работа (певца), а сам певец - и т.д. Ну и по лесам скитается ОН, а не утеха.   
Так что будете на Грамоте - передайте привет и чтоб не морочили больше Вам голову. )))

(+)
14.10

С примерами Софии надо разбираться. На мой вкус там подмена понятий. Инфинитив не входит в состав именного сказуемого, т.е. не является его именно частью, а сам по себе является сказуемым. Так подобные подобные примеры разбирает Розенталь. Разница более чем существенная.

А на Грамоте, похоже, зациклились на одном единственном источнике - к тому же неподтвержденном. Меня там до пятницы забанили - вмешаться не могу. )))) 
Я попозже допишу.

Comment: Завтра там нам должны рассказать, как мы неправы - Ждём)

Comment: Интересно посмотреть будет. Я не дочитал там всех умных мыслей, скулы свело.     
Я в принципе допускаю, что инфинитив может занять место именной части составного сказуемого, но глагольным оно точно не станет. 
Будет ли оно именным - это уж пускай грамматисты голову ломают.

Comment: behemothus ,что-то не пойму, как может здесь "петь"быть дополнением, на какой же вопрос отвечает?(напрашивается вопрос есть что?им.пад., другие как-то звучат не по-русски) и какое простое сказуемое тогда пропущено в неполном?"Работа певца - петь"Было бы дополнением в предложении Певца попросили (о чём?)петь... "Веселое занятие - кататься с горки" -кататься-подлежащее, занятие-сказуемое.Здесь инверсия.Кататься является весёлым занятием. "Его утеха – по лесам скитаться"Утеха какова? в чём состоит? чем является? - всё это вопросы сказуемого, а не дополнения.

Comment: Людмила, на вопрос "Что?". Как вариант. 
А я чего-то не задумываля никогда на какой ворпос фообще отвечает инфинитив в роли дополнения? И всегда ли дополнения обязаны отвечать на какие-то вопросы из заданного наперед списка? 

Вот как трактует "инфинитив в роли дополния" некий источник, авторитность коего обсуждать не буду, просто смысл сказанного оцените. 

Иногда инфинитив при глаголах является дополнением. Инфинитивное дополнение обозначает действие как объект, на который направлено действие другого лица (попросили остаться, приглашают сесть):

Comment: (+)
В твою комнату я велю переселить Андрея со скрипкой (А.Чехов). Прошу уволить меня от дальнейших вопросов (К.Паустовский). Даша заставила Ивана Ильича выпить несколько чашек кофе (А.Толстой). 
--

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/219-sintaksicheskiesvoystvainfinitiva.html

В чем разница-то? Или Вы не признаете инфинитивное дополнение вовсе?

(+)
А вот ваш разбор "Певца попросили петь" (с этих позиций) - не понял совсем. Да, там (тоже) допролнение, но вопрос-то к нему какой?

Comment: @behemothus, а что об этом думает сама справка?

Comment: Серж, простите, вы невнимательны. Я Два раза сказал, что разговоры идут только на форуме.   
Справка пока ничего не думает, её не спрашивали. Можете задать ей этот вопрос.  
На форуме же договорились, что можно трактовать по-разному - в зависимости от автора модели грамматики. Я это формулирую так: Современные модели модели грамматики не дают возможности дифференцировать эти типы сказуемого без привлечения авторитарного мнения. Мне это очень даже понятно. Любой терминологический (или сводящийся к терминологии) бессмыслен, а у нас все действительно свелось к игре терминами.

Comment: @behemothus, я понял, что разговоры ведутся на форуме. Просто подумал, может, задали вопрос справке. Идея хорошая, я задам ей этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

[[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus), на данном сайте с примерами все в порядке. А в примере Насти, взятого с этого сайта - ошибка. Вы безусловно правы, относя пример Насти к простому глагольному сказуемому со второстепенными членами предложения (дополнения).

См.правильный пример: Его утеха - по лесам ***скитаться за зверями.*** (В.А. Жуковский) В данном примере уже СИС.

***Дополнение*** Ответ справочной службы ***Грамма.ру***

***Особенность употребления инфинитива является то, что в предложении он может выполнять функцию любого члена предложения, в том числе и части составного именно сказуемого. Именно такова его роль в предложении "Его утеха - по лесам скитаться со зверями".***

Comment: Серж, боюсь вы сейчас совсем все запутали. Не может структура предложения так поменяться от добавления второстепенных членов.